# Eclipse Milo - writeValue(NodeId, DataValue) is very slow

Tags: eclipse, performance, opc-ua, milo

We are successfully communicating to OPC UA server reading and setting tags. Everything works fine but only issue now is that writing tag value takes a long time around 600ms per tag. So to set 10 tags it takes around 6 seconds which is unacceptable in production environment...please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

How long a write takes is almost always the responsibility of the server, not the client, so there is probably not much else you can do on the Milo client side other than make sure to batch your writes into a single call whenever possible, which it sounds like you are already doing.

You could verify this for yourself by connecting without encryption, capturing the traffic in Wireshark, and verifying that the delay you see is between the request being sent from the client and the response being received from the server.